# Converting an image to byte array and back again

Tags: c#

I realize that this question has been asked before and has answers, but not in this specific way. I have been trying to figure this out for about 7 hours now.

I have a picture that I convert to a byte array to store in an Access database (.mdb)

[Image] -> [byte Array] -> [Access Database(field is an OLE object)]
^ I can do this part fine, done here:

```
public byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    Bitmap BmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
    BmpImage.Save(Application.StartupPath + @"\unmodified.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
    PartPhoto.Image.Save(mStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    byte[] imgAsByte = mStream.ToArray();
    return imgAsByte;
}
```

Then I Store all of my data in my database like this:

```
    Part p = new Part();
    p.PartCode = IPC.Text; 
    p.PartName = IPN.Text;
    p.PartDesc = IDESC.Text;
 -->p.PartPhoto = ImageToByte(PartPhoto.Image);
    p.PartSize = size;
    p.PartWeight = weight;
    p.PartType = IPT.Text;
    p.LeadTime = ILT.Text;
    p.PartCost = ICOST.Text;
    p.PartQuantity = IQNT.Text;

    d.Insert(p);
```

The Insert method does this:

```
 command.CommandText = "Insert INTO PartInfo (PartCode, PartName, PartDesc, PartPhoto, PartSize, PartWeight, PartType, LeadTime, PartCost, PartQuantity) VALUES('" + p.PartCode + "', '" + p.PartName + "', '" + p.PartDesc + "', '@Pic', '" + p.PartSize + "', '" + p.PartWeight + "', '" + p.PartType + "', '" + p.LeadTime + "', '" + p.PartCost + "', '" + p.PartQuantity + "')";
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Pic", p.PartPhoto);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It shows up in my database (in the OLE object field) as long binary data. 
I read from the database into a DataGridView like this:

```
 String query = "SELECT * FROM PartInfo WHERE PartName CONTAINS " + "\"" + PN + "\"";
 connection.Open();
 da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
 da.Fill(dt);
```

I then call:

```
PartGrid.DataSource = d.dt;
PartGrid.Refresh();
```

To refresh the grid.

Here is my problem. I can't read the byte array back from the DataGridView. I tried a couple different ways, always getting the same error: "Parameter is not valid"

```
byte[] picBytes = (byte[])PartGrid.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(picBytes);
Image partPic = Image.FromStream(ms); //ERROR: "Parameter is not valid"
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(partPic);
bmp.Save(Application.StartupPath + @"\test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
return partPic;
```

I call convert from byte array to image like this:

```
PartPhoto.Image = ImageFromByte(e.RowIndex);
```

Like I said, I've been stuck on this for hours now, and it's getting irritating.

Comment: It would serve you well to research what SQL injection is.

Comment: FYI: Not related to your issue, but you could use some `using`s in there. You are using several classes that implement `IDisposable` but you are not properly disposing them.

Comment: @Cory: I am disposing everything later. The code posted I pulled out of their methods because the whole method is not important

Comment: does this contain byte[] PartGrid.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value?

Comment: The OLE object field type means it embeds an OLE header before the BLOB data; when you retrieve it, the `Image` doesn't know what to do with that header data. Either don't use an OLE field type, or strip the OLE header before you put the bytes into the `Image`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Try using [System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) to convert your image to a byte array and [System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) to convert it back.